# Webpack MiniCSSExtractPlugin: cacheGroups depending on import file name

Tags: webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm looking for help with MiniCSSExtractPlugin and the `cacheGroups` feature.

I have a single JavaScript entry file `index.js` which imports 2 Sass files like so:

`import './style.scss'
import './editor.scss'`

What I'd like to end up with is two CSS files - `style.css` and `editor.css`.

Is this possible to achieve with the `cacheGroups` option mentioned [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#extracting-css-based-on-entry)?

I haven't been able to work out to modify this example to get it to work.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?